# Can a factory reset really fix proximity sensor problem?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, proximity-sensor

The screen on my Alcatel Idol 3 goes black when making or answering a call. This suggests that the proximity sensor may be bad. The Phone Tester app indicates that the proximity sensor reports "near" all the time. A customer support rep had be do a reset (edit: wipe system cache) on my phone (not factory reset). This did not resolve the problem. He then suggested doing a factory reset and get back with him to submit a warranty claim if that didn't work. What are the chances that a factory reset will resolve this problem?

Comment: Next to zero... But if you are going to request an RMA for it, you should do it just in case. Proximity Sensor issues are generally a hardware problem, a factory reset will only correct it if somehow the stored thresholds for the sensor got corrupted which is highly unlikely since this is stored in a privileged system file. If you are rooted, you may be able to modify these thresholds manually, but this will void your warranty and only has a 50/50 chance of working at best. It is generally best to get the device repaired/replaced under warranty if that is an option.

Comment: There is 50/50 chance that it will work. You can perform factory reset if it doesn't "fix" sensor than it's hardware problem and need to be repaired/replaced